# A question in Number Theory - prove there exist m>2010 s.t f(m) is not prime

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $$f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_nx^n$$ be a polynomial with $$a_n \in Z,n>0,a_n\neq0$$ Prove that there
exists some natural number $$m>2010$$ such that $$|f(m)|$$ is not a prime number.

I tried to look at f(m) mod m, and i assumed m is relatively prime to a0, so f(m) is reversible mod m. but I didn't know how to continue to prove it is not a prime number.

I would like to get help with that.
Thanks

Comment: You might find [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_for_primes#Prime_formulas_and_polynomial_functions) useful. Also, I think you meant $a_ix^i$ inside that $\sum$ there.

Comment: In fact, you can probably just choose $m=|2011\cdot\prod\limits_{k=0}^{n}a_k|$.

Comment: @barakmanos Provided that no $a_k$ is zero... But yes, your choice seems simply right

Comment: What if $a_0=\pm1$?

Comment: @Michael: With my suggestion, $m$ will still be larger than $2010$.

Comment: @mathifold.org: $a_k\neq0$ is provided within the question, but I think that my suggestion is not working perfectly (probably needs some refinement).

Comment: @barakmanos, Only $a_n\neq0$ is provided.  If $a_0=1$, then $f(m)=1+my$, will not be a multiple of $m$.  Why will it not be prime?

Comment: @Michael: Relying on the obvious mistake in the formula of $f(x)$, I'm pretty sure that the same mistake applies for the restrictions below it (i.e., I think OP meant $\forall{i}\in[0,n]:a_i\in\mathbb{Z},a_i\neq0$).

Comment: @Michael: A simpler solution would be $m=|2011a_0|$, but the case of $a_0=\pm1$ is definitely a problem to be reckoned with (i.e., my solution is not perfect).

Comment: @kate: It seems more like the other post is a duplicate of this one, but since this one has no answer while the other one does I agree with you that this post should be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Just take $m$ to be some multiple of $a_0$. Then everything will be multiple of $a_0$. Perhaps we have bad luck and $|f(m)|$ is in fact $a_0$... but it cannot happen for all the multiples of $m$ greater than 2010: simply consider that $f(x)=a_0+xg(x)$ with $g$ polynomial; if $x=m$ is $ka_0$, then $f(m)=(kg(ka_0)+1)a_0$, and $kg(ka_0)+1$ won't be $0$ or $-2$ for all the values of $k$ large enough.

Comment: As Michael pointed out, this answer is not valid if $a_0=\pm 1$ :-(